# Store multi value from database into one variable

Tags: php, mysql

I want to store multiple product IDs from my database into one variable.

Ex: store (01, 02, 03 from database) into `$productid` and when I get `$productid` to show it should be displayed like this:

```
<p>Product ID : <?php echo $productid; ?></p>
```

Product ID : 01, 02, 03

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PHP's [`join()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.join.php) function:

```
$productid = join(', ', $items)
```

Comment: can you tell how to store product id from database to one variable? i don't know how to do that.

Comment: In the example you removed from your question, you added all ID's from the database into the array $items. If you put this line underneath that loop, you join all the items from that array into 1 string, separated by a comma and a space.